# How to Import multiple csv files into QGIS 3.22.2?

Tags: python, csv, qgis

I want to import multiple csv files at once into QGIS. The files have Lat/Long data. I want the files to project the points. Basically I want the same results from importing the csv files as I would if I used Data Source Manager-Delimited Text with Point Coordinates selected and the x-field and y-field set to Long/Lat respectively.

I keep coming across the same python code on numerous forums. While I can get the files to import as tables, I can not get them to load with geometry (a next stage problem will also be getting the timestamp to load as date instead of a string, I may have to refactor all the files).

Here's the code available on forums which results in loading broken links (my files have column headers "Lat" and "Long"):

```
import glob, os

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "C:/File Path/"

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv)  
# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
    uri ="file:///"+path_to_csv + fname+"encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Long", "Lat","epsg:4326")
    name=fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

This code will load layers, but with a warning triangle for "Unavailable Layer". Clicking on the triangle opens the "Repair Data Source" window. I can manually select the file and repair the link. But then it is nothing more than a table with all fields as strings.

If I run the code like this I get the files to import, but only as tables and without geometry:

```
import glob, os

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "C:/Users/DanielStevens/Documents/Afghanistan Monitoring/Phase 2/Border Crossing/Crossing Polygons/Pakistan/"

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv)  
# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
    uri ="file:///"+path_to_csv + fname
    "encoding=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&crs=%s" % ("UTF-8",",", "Long", 
    "Lat","epsg:4326")
    name=fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

How do I get the CSV files to batch import with geometry (Lat Long projecting points)?

Answer (score 0):

I modified what you had to the line below and it worked perfectly. I removed the encoding because my data wasn't UTF-8.  Not sure if that's what did it.

```
uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:3857&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "lon", "lat")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it help with part of the issue, using a csvt file when importing csv helps force the data types (a pain if you have a number of files especially if the file names change e.g. When a new batch needs to be processed). I was thinking about writing some python that would read the csv, create a csvt with the same filename and populate the file with the right number of column definitions. In the end, as I only have 30 files, it was quicker to use notepad to make the csvt and then rename it accordingly. I have also found that converting date time fields to Oracle date time is handled more consistently in Qgis. Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There is a cool QGIS plugin that does so. Its name is [CSV Batch Import](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/csv_batch_import/).

It allows browsing for a CSV files directory. Then recursively import all CSV files inside that directory as layers in QGIS.

Comment: Don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.